# Merge observable sequences where some are async and preserve order

Tags: javascript, rxjs

As an example, I have two observable sequences, "data1" and "data2" that I'm looking to merge together into one observable sequence, while preserving the initial order.

When the two observable sequences have no asynchronous work—here modeled with a small delay—this is easily doable with `Rx.Observable.merge`. However, with this approach, any asynchronous work destroys the order.

Is it possible to merge observable sequences, passing along values if their known and waiting for values not yet known, using the builtin operators? If not, what type of operator should I build?

```js
'use strict';
var Rx = require('rx');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

var end = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(eventEmitter, 'end');

var data1 = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(eventEmitter, 'data1')
  .takeUntil(end);
var data2 = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(eventEmitter, 'data2')
  .takeUntil(end)
  .delay(1000);

Rx.Observable
  .merge(data1, data2)
  .reduce(function(acc, str) {
    return acc + str + ';';
  }, '')
  .subscribe(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });

eventEmitter.emit('data1', '1');
eventEmitter.emit('data2', '2');
eventEmitter.emit('data1', '3');
eventEmitter.emit('data1', '4');
eventEmitter.emit('data2', '5');
eventEmitter.emit('end');

// expected: "1;2;3;4;5;"
// actual: "1;3;4;2;5;"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option: Merge the streams *before* doing the work so that you capture the order, then do the work (using `concat` to maintain order)

```
// synchronous work...but return it as an Observable so that
// concatMap() can use it correctly
var data1Work = function (data) { return Rx.Observable.of(data); };
// asynchronous work...returns an observable with the result
var data2Work = function (data) {
    // cold observable (wont start until concatMap hits it)
    var work = Rx.Observable.of(data).delay(1000);
    // return work;

    // return hot observable (starts immediately)
    hotwork = work.replay();
    hotwork.connect(); // start it now
    return hotwork;


    // alternatively you can start your async operation and return
    // a Promise that will resolve when it is complete if that
    // pattern feels better to you since Promises are always hot
    // and Rx knows how to consume promises
    // return someFuncThatReturnsPromise(data);
};

var data1 = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(eventEmitter, "data1")
    .map(function (d) { return { type: "data1", data: d }; });
var data2 = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(eventEmitter, "data2")
    .map(function (d) { return { type: "data1", data: d }; });

var results = Rx.Observable
    .merge(data1, data2)
    .concatMap(function (d) {
        var workFunc = d.type === "data1" ? data1Work : data2Work;
        return workFunc(d.data);
    });
```

Comment: While this approach does preserve order, it comes with a downside: the asynchronous tasks don't start until `concatMap` gets to that particular piece of work. This means that IO like network requests and file system access ends up being serialized.

Comment: If you aren't worried about running out of memory while buffering the async results, you can make your asynchronous operations *hot* so they start immediately without waiting for `concatMap` to subscribe to them.  I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: I think I should re-read the section on hot and cold observables, and how to convert between the two, because I think I should have thought of that. Thanks.

Comment: After reading a more into this, I have a follow-up question: In your example to return a hot observable you call `work.replay()` to get an observable that will replay to new subscriptions and `hotwork.connect()` to immediately connect to the underlying source (and start the work). We don't do anything with the Disposable that is returned. Does this mean this pipeline will never fully be cleaned up?

Comment: As long as you stay subscribed, everything will cleanup properly.  The consequence of ignoring those disposables is that if you unsubscribe, any async jobs that were already started will continue to run until completion, though you will never observe their eventual results.  Once they complete, they'll get garbage collected.  Effectively you'll waste resources on async operations that are no longer observable.  For example, in the above code if you were to unsubscribe right after issuing 3 `data2` events, those 3 timers which were already started will continue to run until they complete.